# vmrun fails to start the VM (VMware Workstation under Linux)

Tags: vmware-workstation

I want/need to start my VM instances from the command line, or as part of the host boot sequence. 
Also, as part of a script manually launched on the host at will.

The obvious command for such case would be **vmrun start** with the **nogui** option, but this
fails consistently in my 3 hosts running VMware Workstation 7.1.4 under CentOS 5.6 (64 bit):

```
[root@japeto ~/vmware/juno]$ vmrun start juno.vmx nogui
```

Error: The virtual machine needs to be powered on

If I open the vmware GUI and use the point+click method everything works fine. In fact, once a VM instance has been started this way, then the **vmrun start ... nogui** works at it should for other VM instances residing in the same host.

But this doesn't help for a headless operation where I can only access the host via ssh.

Any hints ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need a complete path-from-root for the .vmx file you're starting.

Answer (score 2):

Have you verified that the modules are loading correctly?

the vmrun command doesn't always auto-load the modules successfully.

load them manually  (/etc/init.d/vmware start)   and try vmrun again.

Answer (score 2):

I got this solution from another forum - and it seems to solve the issue:

```
su - -c "vmrun start /export/vmware/juno/juno.vmx nogui"
```

Comment: Later, the error had turned into `Error: The operation was canceled`. It looks like vmrun needs to have a session opened. If launched manually after the system is up, vmrun works as it is expected to work.

Comment: I got around the `operation was canceled` error using the -T flag: `vmrun -T player start ~/vmware/winxp/winxp.vmx nogui`, or for workstation: `vmrun -T ws start ~/vmware/winxp/winxp.vmx nogui`